# Python Numpy with Datafame np.select with Array values

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe

I'm trying to generate a new column based on multiple conditions of various columns. My code runs without traceback errors. Below is a snippet of the dataframe and code.

[image: This is the starting data]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dfc = pd.read_csv(r'C:\\Users\\...01.csv', header='infer')

condition = [dfc['N']==0, dfc['count']==dfc['N'], (dfc['count'] > dfc['N']) & (dfc['N'] != 0)]
rng_result = [str(dfc['i']) + '-' + str(dfc['a']),'None','None to Many'] 
dfc['rng'] = np.select(condition, rng_result, np.nan)

dfc.to_csv(r'C:\\Users\\...R_01.csv', index=False)
```

It might be that I don't understand numpy, the middle and last **conditions** come out fine. The first condition provide an array, which is not wanted. I want a string with the rows 'i' and 'a' value as I typed it below.

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide the input and the expected output **as text** in the question, so others can easily reproduce it? Also, if I'm reading the data correctly, the only columns that impact 'rng' are i and a - right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conditions are not readily apparent from the question, but is the question intended to address the following? I'm using `np.where()` to combine strings in the case of 'True'.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

data = '''
count,i,a,N
1,1.4,1.4,0
1,0,0,1
2,110,140,0
3,0,0,3
4,3.5,5.1,0
4,19,22,0
'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep=',')
df['rng'] = np.where((df['N'] == 1)|(df['N'] == 3), None, df['i'].astype(str)+'-'+df['a'].astype(str))
df
count   i   　　a     　　N rng
0   1   1.4 　　1.4   　　0 1.4-1.4
1   1   0.0 　　0.0   　　1 None
2   2   110.0   140.0   0   110.0-140.0
3   3   0.0 　　0.0   　　3 None
4   4   3.5 　　5.1   　　0 3.5-5.1
5   4   19.0    22.0    0   19.0-22.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can this be modified for more conditions and choices? Like the condition df['count'] > df['N'] would result in "many".

Comment: Conditions can be added with &(and) or|(or).

Comment: It does not work to have more than 2 conditions (Cons) because when I have 3 Cons I get the error. "TypeError: where() takes from 1 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given." This is my mental picture of np.where( Con_1 | Con_2, choice_1, choice_2 ) because Con_3 and choice_3 is not allowed, but I want 3.

Comment: `np.where` has two choices: true='A', False='B'. You can't do more than that. It is possible to have multiple conditions like `(A==1)|((B==3)&(C==2))`.

Answer (score 1):

Using apply I find it more readable and maintainable

```
data = [["count","i","a","N"],
       [1,1.4,1.4,0],
       [1,0,0,1],
       [2,110,140,0],
       [3,0,0,3],
        [4,3.5,5.1,0],
        [4,19,22,0],
        [50,0,17,21],
        [25,0,0,25]]

def cond(r):
    val = "tbd"
    if r.N==0: val = str(r.i)+"-"+str(r.a) 
    if r["count"]==r.N: val = "None"
    if (r['count'] > r['N']) and (r['N'] != 0): val = 'None to Many'
    return val

df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])
df["rng"] = df.apply(lambda r: cond(r), axis=1)
```

Comment: I'm a little confused in the if statements. "i,a,N" are all columns. In the line:  if r.N==0: val = str(r.i)+"-"+str(r.a) should this be corrected to: if r['N']==0: val = str(r['i'])+"-"+str(r['a'])  ?

Comment: I've used mixed conventions for accessing columns. r.N is synonymous with r["N"]. Some code I typed,  other code I copy/pasted....